# Boost filesystem iterator

Tags: boost, boost-filesystem

Just starting to learn boost::filesystem.

1. What is a difference between directory_iterator and basic_path::iterator?
2. Do the iterators iterate files in lexicographical order?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `path::iterator` iterates through the directory that form the path. If a path is `/a/b/c/d`, it will iterate over `/`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

   `directory_iterator` will instead iterate through files in a directory.
2. No, `directory_iterator` will not sort files, they'll be returned in the same order as your operating system calls do.